# Understanding criteria in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Could you possibly explain what exact Criteria object represents in Hibernate? I have read Criteria API documentation and haven't understood general purpose of that object. What exact information is contained in the `Criteria` instance?

Consider the following code example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "partner.partner_statistic")
public class PartnerStatistic {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "partner_id")
    private Integer partnerId;
    //Getters, Setters
}
```

We have created `Criteria` object by the invocation of `Session.createCriteria(PartnerStatistics.class);`. What information is assembled in the object that we've created? Does criteria query act likes `Builder design pattern` for the query?

Comment: Was https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate%204%20criteria insufficient?

Comment: @JasonC Is it rhetorical question?

Comment: No, it is not rhetorical. This information is readily available in clear sources with examples, I was wondering what went wrong in your research efforts.

Answer (score 1):

`Criteria` in Hibernate represent the same thing as the English word: criteria - for a search in this case.

The example taken from the very first paragraph of the documentation for [`Criteria`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) answers your "design pattern" question:

```
 List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
     .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Iz%") )
     .add( Restrictions.gt( "weight", new Float(minWeight) ) )
     .addOrder( Order.asc("age") )
     .list();
```

The [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/) has a short but informative [chapter on Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html) which addresses your question among others.

All of this is [easily findable in the official documentation and elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate%204%20criteria).